# Currently, is Ruby on Rails deployment a fairly practical solution?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Is it true that with passenger (mod_rails), the deployment of Rails is fairly simple?  But how about how practical it is, considering it in the competitive software field?  Is it true that if deploying Python or PHP framework based website, it can cost just a fraction of a Rails deployment?  I am sure there will be a time when Rails deployment is very comparable to other frameworks, but I'd like to get some idea in the highly competitive software field, how competitive Rails is, compared to Python or PHP based frameworks, supporting similar concurrent user requests.

Comment: What would you like to know? If it's easy to install? If it's high-performant? What do you want to build? WHat do you already know? Ruby, Python and PHP are all easy to use, easy to install and capable of powering high-performant web sites (and more). Please be more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Naturally using something like PHP will require less setup, because apache/{insert_web_server_here} doesn't have to hook into a middleware just to run the application. All it needs is to load php module and it's off and running.

However, I wouldn't let that scare you away from deploying Rails applications. Passenger really makes it easy, as it literally walks  you step by step via the command line, and tells you what to put in certain Apache config files etc.

Another advantage of using Passenger is that it uses REE(Ruby Enterprise Edition) in that it is significantly faster than MRI due to their enhanced garbage collection solution etc.

Comment: so does that mean it is better not to use Ruby 1.9.2 and stick to REE for Ruby 1.8.7?

Comment: @動靜能量 , unfortunately Passenger does not support 1.9* yet, so 1.8.7 is currently your only option with Passenger.

Comment: @Mike Lewis That's not true. Passenger works fine with Ruby 1.9.2.

Comment: I should of said REE doesn't support 1.9 my mistake